# Spring Boot Tries to Access A Post Request URL but shows GET not supported

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http, http-status-code-405

I just started to learn Spring Boot today, and I wanted to create a GET/POST request for my Spring Boot Project. When I tried to access the URL that has the post request it shows 405 error saying that "Request method 'GET' not supported".

I think it is something wrong about my code for the POST request, but I don't know where I did wrong. I tried to search for the a tutorial that teaches how to write a proper GET/POST request, so I couldn't find anything good.

If you guys have any good website that teaches basic HTTP requests in Spring Boot, that will be great. I tried to find answers at StackOverflow, but I didn't find anything answers.

The Spring Boot project I have been using is the one from the official Spring.io website: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

I wanted to call the POST request for my project so I have a better understanding of the HTTP.

Here is the source code for the controller:
    package hello;

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET;
import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.POST;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {
    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    // GET Request
    @RequestMapping(value="/greeting", method = GET)
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), name);

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/testpost", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String testpost() {
        return "ok";
    }

}
```

Here is the source code for the Application:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And here is the source code for the Greeting Object
    package hello;

```
public class Greeting {

    private final long id;
    private final String content;

    public Greeting(long id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

I can get the GET request working by using the "/greeting" URL.
I tried to access the "/testpost" url but it shows 405 error that the GET method is not supported.

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'GET' not supported
```

Comment: how you are requesting "testpost" ? from postman or in browser similar to "/greeting"

Comment: I try to visit  http://localhost:8080/testpost by directly opening in browser.

Comment: That the problem. You need to do a post request by Postman or any other software. checkout this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57282858/3204335

Answer (score 3):

If you try to open the http://localhost:8080/testpost by directly opening in browser, it won't work because opening in browser makes a GET request.

I am not sure how you are trying to do a post request, I tried to do the same post request from postman and able to get the response. Below is the screenshot.
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to make post request directly from web browser which will not work. 
When you hit a URL directly from web browser address bar, it is considered as GET request. Since in your case, there is no GET API as /testpost , it is giving error.

Try to use rest client such as *Postman* or *curl command* to make post request.

I tried your post end-point with postman and it is working properly. PFA snapshot for your reference.[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From where you are trying POST request. If from browser windows you calling POST call, then it will not work, browser will send only GET request. Have you tried from postman or from UI side. It will work.